# node_module Setting up custom builds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm really lost.
I've read about using npm install etc
and downloading the latest packages.

This is great. 
But right now I'm copying and pasting those files into my build.

I thought that the purpose of this was to have the whole package but only create a .js file for the modules you use.
Which would make sense in angular to have dependencies.

But what I cannot figure out - how do I take things to the next level - next step?
In other words 
- **after I've downloaded the package I want, let's say angular-bootstrap ui
Is there a way, if I only use datepicker in my project (dependency), that something will compile a .js file from the bootstrap ui that only includes the datapicker?**

What is that something?
Could someone please help me out or at least point me to a resource to better understand?

My ultimate goal is to be able to download the packages that are useful and only include the portions in my dependencies. (IFFF I am understanding this correctly. If I'm not could someone please educate me)?

For example, you see on github all the time. And people have access to entire source. But surely people don't use a 158Kb file when they only need part of it , do they?

I'm currently coding in Sublime Text 3 and Visual Studio 2015 (community)
And using Prepros for my preprocessing (handles .js, .scss beautifully)

Answer (score 0):

Installing all or part of a package depends really on how the package is designed.  Some libraries have a 'core' library and then allow you to select different components, others require you to take everything.

Even so install everything doesn't mean it's included in your web build, that really depends on your build process. You maybe using a "build a dist js" from the js files find in the index.html type build.  So if your package is componentised, you may only refer to a subset of the many files required in a full library.

tl-dr: Depends on how the library is designer and your build process on what you include.